# Modify this Powershell custom input box to store multiple variables?

Tags: powershell, textbox, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

This  textbox was a powershell tip of the week and i really like it.
But I didn't manage to work with it to have 2 variables or even 3 in one input window.

Does anyone know how to do this ? Any help is upvoted immediately.

The Code of the Textbox is here : [Input Textbox](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730941.aspx)

The full code is here :

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Data Entry Form"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {$x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
    {$objForm.Close()}})

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Please enter the information in the space below:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

$x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to repeat adding a few more text boxes:

```
$OKButton.Add_Click({
    $x=$objTextBox.Text
    $y=$objTextBox2.Text
    $z=$objTextBox3.Text
    $objForm.Close()})

...

$objTextBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,65) 
$objTextBox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox2) 

$objTextBox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,90) 
$objTextBox3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox3) 

...

$x,$y,$z
```

You might need to adjust the Y locations of the OK & Close buttons.